# Installing local package with "pip install -e ." does not update instalation

Tags: pip, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I am working on a small package locally, and want to install it in editable mode so that when I make changes to it I don't have to reinstall after every change. When I install using `pip install .` everything works as expected, however when I change it to `pip install -e .`, the package does not update the modules contained in utils.py on install, nor when modules are changed. Here is my **init**.py:

```
from .utils import *
```

and my setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

with open("README.md", "r", encoding="utf-8") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setup(
    name="mypackage",
    version="0.1.4",
    packages=find_packages(include=["mypackage"]),
    include_package_data=True,
    author="myname",
    description="placeholder",
    long_description=long_description,
    url="github.here",
    license="GNU GPLv3",
    install_requires=[
        "mypackage",
        "pandas",
        "matplotlib",
        "numpy",
        "ipykernel",
    ],
)
```

I have already tried to change `packages=find_packages()`, and `install_requires=["pandas", "matplotlib", "numpy", "ipykernel",]`, which did not fix the issue.

edit: Here is the project file format-

```
mypackage
|---mypackage
|---|---__pycache__
|---|---__init__.py
|---|---utils.py
|---mypackage.egg-info
|---notebooks
|---|---test.ipynb
|---README.md
|---.gitattributes
|---setup.py
```

Comment: My guess is that you need to uninstall the package, since you first installed it in non-editable mode, before installing it again in editable mode.

Comment: Maybe edit your question to show the project's file and directory tree structure. -- Note: there is no need for `mypackage` in `install_requires`, it should be removed, otherwise I guess maybe this would cause `pip` to install a `mypackage` from _PyPI_.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I just created a fresh environment, and only ran "pip install -e .", on python 3.9.13.
I "installs" correctly, returning:
`Installing collected packages: mypackage
Running setup.py develop for mypackage
Successfully installed mypackage`
but when I go to import it with:
`import mypackage as mp`
I get the error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mypackage'`

Comment: Then there must be something wrong with your `setup.py`. Unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with setuptools to help you with that.